# How to adapt a sump pump for shallower water?

Tags: sump-pump

Is there any way to adapt a sump pump so it slurps off 2 mm (0.08") water on the floor? Mine only picks up from 8 mm (0.3") or more.

Comment: Crete a depression in the floor to collect the water and for the pump to sit in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because that's not what a sump pump does.

There are specialized "floor sucker" dewatering pumps that are specially adapted to suck close to the floor level, though even there you may be pushing the limits expecting to get below 1/8"/3mm.

A wet vacuum will pull that last little bit of water off the floor.

Adding a sump (a hole in the floor for the pump to sit in)  would be the way to make a sump pump work well at getting 2mm water off the floor surface.

Comment: This question suggests a pump model that can do 1/16" https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/212159/18078

Comment: agree.  "Have a sump."